# Getting Bad Request error when trying to GET request Organizations endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, aws-organizations

I am trying to make a GET request to the following Organizations endpoint:

```
curl --request GET \
\--url 'https://organizations.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListRoot&Version=2016-11-28' \
\--header 'Accept: application/json' \
\--header 'x-amz-region: us-east-1'
```

However, I am getting a Bad Request error. I have verified that I am using the **correct credentials** and that I am in the **correct region**. I have also tried making the request with different curl options, but I am still getting the same error.

The authentication and permissions (Administration Access) are working because I get 200 when i request AIM service.

The response I get is:

```
<Message>The action or operation requested is invalid. Verify that the action is typed correctly.</Message>
```

Also, sending request via CLI works good:

```
aws organizations list-accounts
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

- **Request:**

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://organizations.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListRoot&Version=2016-11-28' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'x-amz-region: us-east-1'
```

- **Response:**

```
<Message>The action or operation requested is invalid. Verify that the action is typed correctly.</Message>
```

Answer (score -1):

Could it be a typo? At least that's my initial assumption reading the error response back from AWS.

I expect you're trying to use the `ListRoots` action, as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_ListRoots.html). However, you're specifying the action to be `ListRoot` in your curl!

Comment: I tried both ```ListRoots``` and ```ListRoot``` - didn't work.